# Selection of the utilization factor for the calculation of the transformer for the DAB converter

Tags: power-supply, transformer, electromagnetism, magnetic-flux, dual-active-bridge

DAB Converter:

[image]

When calculating the parameters of a transformer, it is necessary to know the utilization factor of the transformer (Ku).
Here it is 0.3.

[image]

The utilization factor of the transformer depends on the type of rectifier:
[image]

As far as I understand, 0.3 was chosen as for a half-wave rectifier.
But the output is a full bridge.

**Why is utilization factor not 0.8?
My assumptions:**
A. This is mistake. DAB uses a utilization factor of 0.8. If I choose 0.3 is that bad?
B. This is due to the peculiarities of DAB operation (phase shift, etc.)
С. Is this some headroom for the transformer? I substituted 0.8 and the area fell by almost half.

**Additional question:**
What determines the choice of Bm (maximum flux density)? Does it depend on the choice of planar or classic pulse transformer?

P.s. Here it is said about the calculation for a planar transformer. I want to use classic pulse transfomer.

Comment: I have found this [document](https://inderjitsingh87.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/1/4/21144104/edc_transformer_utilization_factor_for_rectifier_circuits.pdf) which discusses the transformer utilization factor and you may find your answer there. Regarding the flux density, its selection depends on the acceptable core losses at your operating point and how far you want to stay away from saturation. I looked at it in a recent [PDF](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Current%20and%20flux%20balancing%20for%20the%20DAB.pdf) on dc-drift compensation for a DAB converter.

Comment: If you are using the output bridge for a boosted output voltage, then it will be behaving as two diodes in series i.e. a half wave rectifier. The other two MOSFETs won't play a role in a booster as far as I can tell. I'm mentioning this based on your previous questions.

Comment: @VerbalKint, thank you for the answer! This is a very helpful document!

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you for the answer! Yes, it will work in both buck and boost mode. I asked the developers of that design with a wide output range, they also said to present the DAB as a Buck / Boost converter (mentally removing the transformer), which you then spoke about. And if the current on the inductance is higher than on the load, then you can increase the output voltage. It's just a little more complicated than phase shift.

Comment: @VerbalKint, I have studied this document, and the approximate same value of utilization factor was obtained there. For one diode (0.287 ≈ 0.3) and for a full bridge about 0.8). But so far I'm still not sure why utilization factor 0.3 was used for the full bridge in my example. Either it's a mistake or it's down to DAB management.

Comment: @Delta, well, did you calculate then the TUF for the DAB converter? I have derived the dc output current and the rms sec. side current in this [PDF](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20DAB.pdf) and you have a DAB example in my [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf).

Comment: @Delta, I ran a quick sim and calculation then the TUF for the DAB is greater than 0.8, I read 0.89 actually for a 50% duty ratio on the transformer sec. side. I will post a reply later on.

Comment: @VerbalKint, Thank you for taking the time to answer this question and run the simulation! I will rate the given post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformer utilization factor determines the amount of apparent power circulating in the secondary with respect to the delivered active power. It resembles a bit the power factor but we are talking here of dc power absorbed by a receptor. This [document](https://inderjitsingh87.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/1/4/21144104/edc_transformer_utilization_factor_for_rectifier_circuits.pdf) describes the notion in simple and understandable terms.

For a dual-active-bridge converter or DAB, we first need to determine the amount of power delivered to the load. This is an exercise I carried in a [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20DAB.pdf) I posted in my [webpage](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm) recently. Calculations are not overly complicated when you consider a single-phase-shift (SPS) modulation technique. Then you can determine secondary side rms current and voltage. For the rms voltage, we have a symmetrical waveform swinging between \$V_{out}\$ for 50% of the time and \$-V_{out}\$ for the rest. The rms voltage is thus \$V_{out}\$:

[image]

With these calculations, the TUF is around 0.7 for the given operating point.

A quick sim using the DAB from my [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and there you go:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!!! This completely solved my issue.

Comment: I am happy if it useful : )